# Hyperlinks to network drive in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, hyperlink

My database was built in ArcMap 10.6. I have a feature class with a text field "Photopath". The destination was copy-pasted from my network drive in Windows File Explorer. The link is active and will open the .jpg images for the entire feature class when using ArcMap.

I have started to migrate to ArcGIS Pro 2.8. None of these links works in ArcGIS Pro. Now we have to copy-paste them into our Windows File Explorer to find the issue.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example of my Photopath]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Configure Pop-up -> Add Text to the Pop-Up -> Edit Pop-Up Element -> Hit the dropdown button for Hyperlink -> Type {Photopath}.

This created a direct link to the network drive to open the image.